# Journey Builder Custom Activity Send Trigger

Tags: journeybuilder, custom, heroku

I'm very new to both custom activities (and express/postmonger generally as I'm usually coding in Ruby), but I've got a use-case where this seems like the only valid option.

Basically I want to trigger an email to someone who has a data relationship to the current subscriber in the journey. I've got a simple activity setup with an app on Heroku but I can't seem to figure out where to make the POST request back to SFMC with the data to trigger the send.

Not looking for an extremely detailed answer, just someone to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer to this is no longer needed as I've discovered how to do this on my own.